# How to access to a position of a Fragment listview item from another Fragment

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, fragment

I have a Fragment which contains a listview of some tones.And I have another Fragment which contains a listview of favorited items from the First Fragment.
If a user in the main Fragment wants to unmark an Item as favorite, I have to check if that specific item is playing or not. Hence, I need to access to an int variable named `position` from my main Fragment.

a method inside **Favorite Fragment:**

```
public void stopSong(int position){
  int selectedSong = soundList.get(position).getRes();
}
```

access that method from **Main Fragment**:

```
  if (MainFragment.isPlaying==true){
  MainFragment z = (MainFragment) MainFragment.mainFragment;
  z.getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(MainFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID);
  if (z!=null){
    z.stopSong(position);//position that I need to get from Favorite Fragment method
  }
}
```

Can you help me with this, please?

Comment: you can use shared preference for this or send position using bundle

Answer (score 0):

use FragmentTransaction to switch the fragment, and add a argument

`z.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());`

later,execute the method `stopSong`

**I advise into the service to stop the music, should not be controlled from UI[Fragment]**